# Othogonal Dimensions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function, dimensions, qgis-customization

I wonder if there is a solution for Orthogonal Dimensions in QGIS. At the moment i have to export my projects to AutoCAD and make the dimensioning process there. As i could fully change my workflow to QGIS exept this part, I would like to find a smart solution for this also in QGIS, because the licencing for AutoCAd is pretty expensive.

[image]

As shown in the picture above i need a solution, to make Orthogonal Dimension from fixed topographie like buildings. In the current add in I use in AutoCAD, i draw a line with no fixed length through two points. The program automatically gives me start point with "0.0" and Endpoint with the lenght of the line. Afterwards I just select the points i want to usw dor the orthogonal Dimensioning and i automatically get perpendicular lines to the points with the given length and also the distance from the point "0.0".

It don't have to be the same layout, but the output should be same. It also should be possible to move the numbers for increased visibility.
If anyone knows a add in which can do this, or a code, i would appreciate your knowledge.